# Como convertir o crear un string a elementos en js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Probablemente no presenté bien la pregunta

Soy novato en codigo json y necesito crear un gráfico en canvas con javascript.
Las consultas en php y mysql se realizan de forma correcta y perfctamente convierto los resultados en un array y este en codigo json para trabajar con los resultados en un archivo javascript.

estoy usando el framework Chart Js para crear los gráficos.
Mi conflicto está en esta parte, donde de manera manual se completa así

labels: ["mes1", "mes2"],
data: [500, 550],

ahora los datos de labels y data los obtengo desde una consulta sql

tengo el siguiente codigo

```
var nom = '';
for(var i in d2){
    nom += '"'+d2[i].N+'",';
}
nom = nom.substring(0,nom.length-1);

var punto = '';
for(var j in d2){
    punto += d2[j].P+',';
}
punto = punto.substring(0,punto.length-1);
```

El error ocurre cuando le paso estas variable a los datos correspondientes, es decir:

```
labels: [nom],
data: [punto],
```

Al ejecutar el codigo me toma cada variable como un solo string, y necesito que los tome como varios valores separados por comas.
No se que tipo de conversión debo hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te los toma como strings, porque tu los estas definiendo como strings. Chart.js espera esos valores como arreglos, así que cambia tu código para usar arreglos.

```
var nom = [];
for(var i in d2){
    nom.push(d2[i].N);
}

var punto = [];
for(var j in d2){
    punto.push( d2[j].P );
}
```

Y los usas tal cual:

```
labels: nom,
data: punto,
```